# Delete everything after pattern notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

hi i have XML contain the following lines

```
<size name="S" count="1"  enabled="yes" />
<size name="M" count="1"  enabled="yes" />
<size name="L" count="0"  enabled="no" />
```

i need to keep only the size name and value and delete the rest of the line like the following:

```
<size name="S"/>
<size name="M" />
<size name="L" />
```

can you please tell me how i can do it through Notepad++

Comment: Simple answer: replace `\s*count="[^"]*"\s*enabled="[^"]*"\s*` with `` (empty string.

Comment: Fast way: Replace the _'count="1"  enabled="yes"'_ by Nothing, either reg exp or amnual selecting.

Comment: Using the official documentation can help you : http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(<size name="[^"]+" ).+`
- Replace with: `$1/>`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(               : start group 1
   <size name=" : literally
   [^"]+        : 1 or more character that is not double quote
   "            : double quote
)               : end group
.+              : 1 or more any character
```

- *Check regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Replacement:**

```
$1      : content of group 1
/>      : close tag
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<size name="S" />
<size name="M" />
<size name="L" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without a capture group:

Find what:  `count=".*"`
Replace with: [leave field blank]

Input:

```
<size name="S" count="1"  enabled="yes" />
<size name="M" count="1"  enabled="yes" />
<size name="L" count="0"  enabled="no" />
```

Result:

```
<size name="S" />
<size name="M" />
<size name="L" />
```

Because the `*` quantifier is "greedy" it will sail right through `enabled` to the last double quote in the line.

The pattern will not match beyond the initial line unless you tick the `. matches newline` box (don't do this).